# WPF PropertyChanged event is null after updating property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, updating

I'm struggling with some databinding. In my MainWindow I have 2 buttons which are databound to a property `Result` in a class "Properties" - strictly for holding properties that I will be using for databinding. The buttons are hidden by default, and when I want them to become visible I simply set `Result` property that they are bound to to "True"

I know the databinding is working because if I set the property to a static value, the buttons are visible / not visible. See below for my XAML

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
                        </StackPanel.Resources>

                        <Button x:Name="btnBack" Height="25" Content="&lt;- Back" Visibility="{Binding Path=Result, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, 
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnBack_Click" Margin="0,0,10,0" />

                        <Button x:Name="btnNext" Height="25" Content="Next ->" Visibility="{Binding Path=Result, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, 
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"  Click="btnNext_Click" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
```

So they are bound to "Result" property, and I have `UpdateSourceTrigger=Propertychanged`in my binding.

In my "Properties" class I have the below and AM implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
 bool _result;

    #endregion

    public bool Result {
        get
        {
            return _result;
        }
        set
        {
            _result = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Result");

        }
    }

    #region EVENTS



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
```

But for some reason when I change the property to "True" the PropertyChanged Event is null and therefore the event never fires.

Any idea as to why this is happening? Could it be because this code isn't in my ViewModel and just in a separate class?

Comment: It should be in your view model and your view model should be assigned to your `DataContext`.

Comment: Thanks j giving that a try now. I'll update with resutls

Comment: This works! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have set the DataContext of the window to an instance of your Properties class and that you don't set the DataContext property of any parent element of the StackPanel to something else because the DataContext is inherited.

Please refer to the following sample code. The Buttons do become visible as expected after the 3 second delay:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Properties _viewModel = new Properties();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _viewModel;

        this.Loaded += async (s, e) =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            _viewModel.Result = true;
        };
    }
}

public class Properties : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool _result;
    public bool Result
    {
        get
        {
            return _result;
        }
        set
        {
            _result = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Result");

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Button x:Name="btnBack" Height="25" Content="&lt;- Back" Visibility="{Binding Path=Result, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, 
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="0,0,10,0" />

        <Button x:Name="btnNext" Height="25" Content="Next ->" Visibility="{Binding Path=Result, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, 
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"  Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks for the code reference. I've figured out what the issue was. I didn't mention that I was setting the property from within the class. I guess I was a bit deceptive in my description. The property is not being set from the viewmodel, but from the Properties class itself. Which is obvious bad design and I know that now. Out of curiosity, any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: I was instantiating the Properties class from a usercontrol, inside the MainWindow. Then calling a method inside the properties class to change the Result value. But the buttons are a part of the MainWindow and NOT the usercontrol. Which I'm pretty sure is also bad design, but I want to buttons to stay static when I switch between usercontrols (different views).